# Roll back data before saving to mongoDB database java standalone application

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm new to mongoDB and trying to use mongo database for my desktop application which I use javaFX as frontend.The version of mongo-java-driver is 3.10.1 and up to now can add data to db successfully.I want to perform **Roll Back** if any of textfields are empty.isValidText boolean check whether textfields are empty.Do I really need to **roll back**?If so how can I perform roll back?

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("testDB");
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");

        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("name", nameTxt.getText().toString())
                .append("type", typeTxt..getText().toString())
                .append("count", countText.getText().toString())
                .append("info", infoTxt.getText().toString());
                if (isValidText){
                    coll.insert(doc);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Text Fields are empty");
                }
```

Comment: As per the documentation and pretty much all material on databases like
MongoDB, MongoDB has no sense of transnational queries. It does not store
the previous state, it just updates. here reference -  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/ . So you could check fields first and then go for save record.

Comment: I found it "Until a transaction commits, no write operations".Thank you @HasanuzzamanRana for directing me.